# php lightbox trigger causing errors

Tags: php, forms, triggers, modal-dialog, lightbox

I have added a sortable php table to my page using PHP and have a lightbox setup that when a row is clicked it pulls the ID from the row and displays the appropriate data in a lightbox.

```
  echo "<tr class='LightboxTrigger' data-lightboxid='<?php echo $row['ID'];?>'>";
```

My code for the lightbox trigger is above, and the error I receive when uploading the page is below:

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home1/awaluminium/public_html/orca/timesheets.php on line 436
```

Please can you help me realize where the issue is?

EDIT:

```
  echo "<tr class='LightboxTrigger' data-lightboxid='<?php echo ['ID'];?>'>";
```

This now allows the page to load but doesnt display the appropriate data in the lightbox it is just blank. Has also added a line of >;>;>;>;>; to the top of the div that the form is enclosed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a php opening tag inside of an echo statement, so it looks as if you are already inside php when trying to open it:

```
 echo "<tr class='LightboxTrigger' data-lightboxid='<?php echo $row['ID'];?>'>";
```

try changing this to:

```
 echo "<tr class='LightboxTrigger' data-lightboxid='".$row['ID']."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php shoud out of string
echo "<tr class='LightboxTrigger' data-lightboxid='"<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"'>";
```

or shorter :

```
 echo "<tr class='LightboxTrigger' data-lightboxid='"<?=$row['ID'];?>"'>";
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.